# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView inside an .aar

Tags: android, module, android-recyclerview, dependency-management, aar

I have developed a library module that uses `RecyclerView`. When including the library module to an application using the `compile project(":fuumodule")`, everything works fine. But when I add the generated .aar file to my application that includes this library (`compile(name:'fuumodule', ext:'aar')`), the application crashes when I open an `Activity` from the library module that uses `RecyclerView`.

`Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

But only `RecyclerView` crashes. Every other dependency works in the library module.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, when you add the library as .aar file, the dependency library classes of your library are not included in the .aar file. You can check that in the left pane of Android Studio in Project view under External Libraries > your lib > classes.jar

There is a discussion about this here, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/0ZAP8AVUZVw

> Using an artifact will *not* include it in the aar. The whole point of
>   using remote artifacts is to not rely on jars but instead on the
>   artifact adress so that the project using your 'aa'r can resolve all
>   its dependency graph, find duplicates, resolve conflicts, etc...

So, that dependency, in your case it's RecyclerView, should be added in your app level build.gradle.

Comment: Other dependencies work, like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1`. I have a toolbar in my library module (the .aar) and it doesn't crashes because of it.

Comment: I guess, you would have that appcompat dependency in your app build.gradle also

Comment: Actually, yes. But this was only an example. I have a few other dependencies which I don't have in my app build.gradle and it still works. (Like the gson library, `compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.4'`). I only have the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1` in my app build.gradle.

Comment: So it seems, all the dependencies that the aar library uses should be added to the app build.gradle. right?

Comment: Yes. But I found a solution. When I have the time, I'll post the answer.